# Why does positioning of <script> in HTML for window.onload event matters?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have a form that hides a text input field dynamically, depending on the initial choice of an option field upon loading. After some trial and error, I realise that the `<script>` tag has to be placed below the `<form>` elements in order for this functionality to work:

```
<html>
....
 <body>
....
  <form>
   <select name=choice>
    <option value=0 selected>Default</option>
    <option value=1>Others</option>
   </select>
   <input type=text name=others></input>
  </form>
....
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   function init()
   {
    var A = document.forms[0].choice;
    var B = document.forms[0].others;
    if(A.options[A.selectedIndex].value == 0) B.style.display = 'none';
   }
   window.onload = init();
  </script>
....
 </body>
</html>
```

The event `window.onload` is a global event that is triggered after all resources of the page including DOM, images, frames, etc have loaded. Then, why is it still necessary for the `<script>` tag to be placed below the `<form>` elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your executing the `init function` instead assigning the pointer to the function...

Change:

```
window.onload = init();
```

To:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and HTML works correctly. But I see some miss understand on your code.

```
window.onload = init();
```

This line means use execute init function immediately and set function result as onload event. That is the reason why it works when you place it under form element.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of a typo in your code:

```
window.onload = init();
```

This is actually calling the `init` function immediately (and then setting `window.onload` to undefined). Try:

```
window.onload = init;
```